# Cannot favorite users using polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the system below **users** are able to favorite **styles** in the format of:

```
=> #<Favorite id: 59, user_id: 2, favoritable_id: 15, favoritable_type: "Style", created_at: "2013-04-06 08:47:08", updated_at: "2013-04-06 08:47:08">
```

I have built the system to enable **users** to favorite **users** as well, but for some reason the line `Favorite.create!(:user => user)` is not creating the expected favorite model object when called on **User**, as above when called on **Style**. Instead I am getting nils as below:

```
=> #<Favorite id: 65, user_id: 2, favoritable_id: nil, favoritable_type: nil, created_at: "2013-04-06 09:35:07", updated_at: "2013-04-06 09:35:07">
```

---

---

**Problem is above. Details are below**

---

---

Favorite Class:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :favoritable, :polymorphic => true
 belongs_to :user
 attr_accessible :user
 validates_presence_of :user
 validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:favoritable_type, :favoritable_id]
end
```

Model definitions including favoritable module (see below):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Favoritable

class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Favoritable
```

Favoritable Module:

```
module Favoritable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessible :favorites
    has_many :favorites, :as => :favoritable, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :favorites

    def add_favorite(user)
      self.favorites << Favorite.create!(:user => user)
      save
    end

    def delete_favorite(user)
      self.favorites.where(:user_id => user.id).each do |favorite|
        favorite.destroy
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Favorites Controller:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  def fav_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.add_favorite(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => "update_favorite_disp", :layout => false }
    end
  end

  def delete_fav_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.delete_favorite(current_user)
        format.js { render :action => "update_favorite_disp", :layout => false }
      end  
    end
  end 

  def fav_style
    @style = Style.find(params[:id])
    @style.add_favorite(current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => "update_favorite", :layout => false }
    end
  end 

  def delete_fav_style
    @style = Style.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @style.delete_favorite(current_user)
        format.js { render :action => "update_favorite", :layout => false }
      end  
    end
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the :favoritable model in `add_favorite`:

```
def add_favorite(user)
  Favorite.create!(:user =>user, :favoritable => self)
save
```

`delete_favorite` also needs to delete based on the `:favoritable_id`, instead of `:user_id`:

```
def delete_favorite(user)
  user.favorites.where(:favoritable_id => self.id).each do |favorite|
    favorite.destroy
  end
end
```